# Which article to use?

Tags: articles

The Articles are confusing, look at these two sentences and tell me is there a difference in their meaning.

Assume ( a total of 5 windows in this case)

1a) My ball hit the window of our principal's office.

1b) My ball hit a window of our principal's office.

Both of these sentences are providing the same meaning then what exactly are "a" and "the" conveying?

Comment: Here 1a) is correct because it ensures the required emphasis by using 'the'.  Second is not, because a ball can hit only one window which is clear even without one's having to say.

Comment: But how is  the second one "incorrect"? What if I don't want to emphasize the window of my principal's office but just stating a fact that I hit a window of my principal's office?

Comment: It is not incorrect, it is just that 'when a co-student complains to the principal that a ball hit the window' he/she, probably, will say, "Sir/Madam, while playing, the ball hit the window pane." It is not a matter of grammar-error, but what is more right in a context of this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a) My ball hit **the window** of our principal's office.
This would be used only when there is exactly one window in the principal's office, not when there are five.

1b) My ball hit **a window** of our principal's office.
This is correct if the ball hit one of five possible windows.

However, once the window is known, and is spoken of later, you would say
**The window** my ball hit has been repaired."
regardless how many windows were in the office.

Comment: I'm still going to accept it even though I knew everything you've written. Thanks for the explanation.